# Get attribute and value from generic class

Tags: c#, .net, solr

How do I get attribute name and it's value using IReadOnlyMappingManager ?

I create variable with :

```
mappingManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IReadOnlyMappingManager>();
```

An i use

```
mappingManager.GetFields(typeof(T))
```

But I haven't keys and value for fiels.

Thanks

Comment: Start from the beginning. What are you trying to do?

Comment: How is this related to Solr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear, but maybe something like this is what you want?

```
var props = typeof(IReadOnlyMappingManager).GetProperties();
foreach (var p in props)
    var value = p.GetValue(mappingManager)
```